# No me actualiza el dato cuando el id es un vachar en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy haciendo un update a mi base de datos mysql y el campo de mi id es un **vachar** y el campo que quiero actualizar es un **int**. El problema que me esta sucediendo, es que cuando ejecuto el script para el update, no me lo realiza. A continuación les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

**Consulta SQl:**

```
UPDATE tarea SET completado = '1' WHERE id_tarea = '2001071102'
```

**Respuesta que me da en el phpmyadmin**

> 0 filas afectadas. (La consulta tardó 0.0004 segundos.)

Comment: has probado  si al hacer  un `SELECT` con el mismo `WHERE`  te devuelve resultados ?

Comment: Hola, ¿qué te retorna la consulta `SELECT * FROM tarea WHERE id_tarea = '2001071102'`? Me da la impresión que tu registro con id_tarea no existe 2001071102 ya que en mysql no hay problema si encierras como string el valor a buscar en un campo int

Comment: O, si el valor ya es `1` te devuelve 0 filas afectadas, porque realmente no ocurrió actualización ya que mandas a actualizar con un valor que es el mismo que ya tiene :)

Comment: Todo lo que te han dicho y, si nos pasas tu dataset (phpMyAdmin/Exportar) con algún dato de muestra (si incluyes el `2001071102`, mejor), podremos responderte confirmando las posibles causas que se nos ocurran... :)

Comment: Si prove el select y si el registro existe solo el problema lo tengo cuando y el valor del campo es 3 en el de cumplimiento me lo tiene que cambiar a uno. y es lo que no me lo hace